# Run tika server in aws lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, apache-tika

How would you run tika server in aws lambda. In normal terminal i would do

```
java -jar tika-server.jar
```

But how would i execute the same in aws lambda .I have a python code that requires this server to be available at a specific port.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lambda isn't meant to work like that. Lambdas only runs for a short amount of time and have a maximum execution time of 300s. You just invoke Lambdas they do something and terminate thereafter. Lambdas are for serverless code and you need a server.

You could probably either try running tika using Elastic Beanstalk or spin up your EC2 instance directly and run that command from the command line.

Comment: What if someone just needs to run Tika to parse one file for a few seconds and it's done? It's a misconception that Lambda can't be used for regular processing. Even if you do have thousands of files to parse on Tika, you can invoke Lambda thousands of times for each file and even process them all concurrently.

Comment: Look at the question. The op wanted to run a Tika server and use it from Python listening on a specific port. That's not the same as processing files with Tika which you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Use Apache tika lambda layer: https://github.com/shelfio/java-lambda-layer

Note this layer works if you'r resources are in us-east-1 region, else you need to create this by your own.